# How save object to HiddenField in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, hiddenfield

I have updatePanel and hiddenField in it. I need to save object to hiddenField without full pastback (only updatePanel updating).
ViewState can't help, because it works only with full postback.

Comment: What is a `hiddenField`? I know about class `fields` and HTML hidden inputs. Can you clarify?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx

Comment: Did you try handling the [ValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.valuechanged.aspx) event of your `HiddenField` control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the HiddenField control and the control that triggers the event where you set the value within the ContentTemplate tags of the UpdatePanel.  When you put those within the ContentTemplate tags it will post back asyncronously and in your code-behind you will be able to do something like...

```
yourHiddenField.Value = strSerializedVersionOfYourObject;
```

Note that the type of the Value property of a HiddenField control is a string, so if you want to store an object in it, you'll have to serialize it as a string and when you are ready to use it, deserialize it back into your object.